# android apk built with jenkins crashes on device. Everything works fine in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jenkins, gradle

I recently started tinkering around with Jenkins and android. I installed jenkins on my own server and also installed graddle and the android sdk.
Please find my configuration below:
[image: jenkins configuration]

I get a list of generated .apk files, however when installing the debug-app.apk on my device it crashes with the following error:

```
07-24 19:18:34.043 26394-26394/bikeparts.triplustutorials.be.bikeparts E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         Process: bikeparts.triplustutorials.be.bikeparts, PID: 26394
                                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{bikeparts.triplustutorials.be.bikeparts/bikeparts.triplustutorials.be.bikeparts.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "bikeparts.triplustutorials.be.bikeparts.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/bikeparts.triplustutorials.be.bikeparts-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/bikeparts.triplustutorials.be.bikeparts-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "bikeparts.triplustutorials.be.bikeparts.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/bikeparts.triplustutorials.be.bikeparts-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/bikeparts.triplustutorials.be.bikeparts-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
                                                                                             at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Any clue to what would be going wrong?

Gradle file (default generated):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bikeparts.triplustutorials.be.bikeparts"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="bikeparts.triplustutorials.be.bikeparts">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Add the manifest

Comment: Done, it is in the original post

Comment: make sure the apk is signed using v1, and not v2. V2 is the signing method that came with Android 7.

Comment: I'm also fairly new to android. I think at this point I don't need to sign anything. (may be mistaken here). I just want an application that I can test and play around with for now

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue myself. I used graddle command "assemble" instead of "build". Next I made sure that a jdk was added to jenkins.

I resolved everything by manually testing and executing "gradlew assemble" in the workspace of my project.

Comment: can you please tell me how to set up jenkins perfectly ?